# Command for nulifying spaces (String.trim()) in latex

Tags: macros, documentclass-writing

I want to declare a variable in class that takes in the font name from the preamble of the `TeX` file. 
Something like `\docFont{<Variable>}`. Is there a command that could nullify the space key in latex? For example `\docFont{ Arial }` would return the same result as `\docFont{Arial}`.

My `myclass.cls` File is something like this:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2019/04/09 Standard HomeWork Template]
\LoadClass[a4paper,12pt,onecolumn,final]{article}
\RequirePackge{etoolbox}
\def\hFont#1{\gdef\@hFont{#1}}
\def\@hFont{\@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\hFont given}}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{document}{
\RequirePackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{\@hFont}
}
```

And my `*.Tex` file is something like this:

```
\documentclass{myclass}
\hFont{Arial}   %Document Persian Font
\begin{document}
something
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you talking about some sort of `string.Trim()` you would find in other languages? You can check out `\tl_trim_spaces:n` from expl3 – `texdoc interface3` has the documentation.

Comment: @SeanAllred This is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: Can you expand your question with a complete MWE? Due to expansion concerns, the exact context of how you want to use this macro will determine its implementation.

Comment: @SeanAllred edited.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [trimspaces](https://ctan.org/pkg/trimspaces) package for this purpose.

## Simple examples

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimspaces}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\trim}[1]{%
  \trim@spaces@noexp{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\textbar \trim{a bcd ef}\textbar

\textbar \trim{ a bcd ef }\textbar
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is another way that first stores the result of the trimming operation in a macro (`\my@tmp@trimmed`), then expands this macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimspaces}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\trim}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \edef\my@tmp@trimmed{\trim@spaces@noexp{#1}}%
    \expandafter
  \endgroup
  \my@tmp@trimmed
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
X\trim{a bc def}Y

X\trim{ a bc def  }Y
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Overview of the possibilities

The [trimspaces](https://ctan.org/pkg/trimspaces) package offers several variants depending on what you want:

- left-only, right-only or both-sides trimming (left: `\trim@pre@space` and `\trim@pre@space@noexp`; right: `\trim@post@space`, `\trim@post@space@noexp`; both: `\trim@spaces`, `\trim@spaces@noexp`);
- whether you want to expand tokens while trimming, or not (so far, I chose the `@noexp` variant in the examples, that just trims without expanding; otherwise, see `\trim@spaces` in the package documentation and below).

It also allows one to trim the contents of an already-existing macro. Here is the example from the documentation concerning this point:

```
\def\b{ b \foo ! }
\trim@spaces@in\b
```

is equivalent to

```
\def\b{b \foo !}
```

`\trim@pre@space@in` and `\trim@post@space@in` offer analoguous functionality for left-only, resp. right-only trimming.

## Difference between `\trim@spaces` and `\trim@spaces@noexp`

The following example illustrates the functional difference between `\trim@spaces` and `\trim@spaces@noexp`<sup>1</sup>: the former expands tokens from its argument whereas the latter doesn't (they can then be expanded “at the last moment”, which is often desirable).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimspaces}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\storeTrimmedImmediateExp}[2]{%
  \xdef#1{\trim@spaces{#2}}%
}

\newcommand*{\storeTrimmedNoExp}[2]{%
  \xdef#1{\trim@spaces@noexp{#2}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\foo}{[default foo]}
\storeTrimmedImmediateExp{\immediateExp}{ a\foo b } % \foo is expanded now
\storeTrimmedNoExp{\delayedExp}{ a\foo b }          % \foo is not expanded yet
\renewcommand*{\foo}{[updated foo]}


\begin{document}
\textbar \immediateExp \textbar % there is no \foo inside \immediateExp

\textbar \delayedExp \textbar % \foo is expanded after \delayedExp
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Corner cases

This last example explores a few corner cases with various kinds of spaces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimspaces}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\trim}[1]{%
  \trim@spaces@noexp{#1}%
}
\makeatother

% Define \implicitSpace to be \let-equal to a space token
\begingroup
  \def\\{\global\let\implicitSpace= }\\ % cf. TeXbook exercise 24.6
\endgroup

\begin{document}
A\trim{a bc def}B

C\trim{ a bc def }D

E\trim{\ a bc def\ }F % control spaces aren't trimmed

% Implicit space tokens are... sometimes trimmed (?)
G\trim{\implicitSpace a bc def\implicitSpace}H
\end{document}
```

[image]

### **Footnote**

1. The other difference being that `\trim@spaces@noexp` requires an eTeX engine, while `\trim@spaces` doesn't.

Comment: Simple and easy to grasp. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. I realized there was an even simpler method, therefore I have expanded my answer starting with that one, then showing the difference between `\trim@spaces` and `\trim@spaces@noexp`, and finally testing the behavior of `\trim@spaces@noexp` with various kinds of spaces.

Answer (score 5):

Here, I preprocess the argument to `\docfont` and pass the result to `\docfontcore`, which solely for the purposes of demonstration, detokenizes its argument, so that you can see that it gives the originally specified tokens, trimmed of leading and trailing (but not intermediate) spaces.

The last MWE example shows that passing macros poses no impediment to the approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\docfont[1]{%
  \setsepchar{!!!!}% USE SOMETHING NOT IN THE FONTNAMES
  \readlist*\trimmedvar{#1}%
  \itemtomacro\trimmedvar[1]\thetrimmedvar%
  \expandafter\docfontcore\expandafter{\thetrimmedvar}%
}
\newcommand\docfontcore[1]{[\detokenize{#1}]}
\begin{document}
\docfont{ Arial Bold }
\docfont{Arial Bold  }
\docfont{Arial Bold}

\newcommand\myfont{Palatino}
\docfont{ \myfont-oblique }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I will start reading more into this later. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents in pure TeX (no packages required):

```tex
\makeatletter
\long\gdef\@calc@trim< #1 >\@/< #2 >\@/< #3 >\@/< #4 >\@/< #5 >\@/< #6 >\@/< #7 >\@/< #8 >\@/< #9 >\@nihil{%
    \ifcase\numexpr2#3#8\relax\or#2\or#7\or#5\or#1\or#1\fi%
}

\long\gdef\trim#1{%
    \@calc@trim< #1 >\@/< #1>\@/< - >\@/< + >\@/< ? >\@/<#1 >\@/<#1>\@/< 0 >\@/< 2 >\@/< 1 >\@/< 3 >\@/< 2 >\@/< ! >\@nihil%
}
\makeatother
```

Test:

```tex
[\trim{ Arial }]

[\trim{ Arial}]

[\trim{Arial }]

[\trim{Arial}]

[\trim{     }]

[\trim{}]
```

Result:

[image: Result for \trim]